# geom_text position middle on the stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, stacked-bar-chart

```
# Loading data
data(CPS85, package = "mosaicData")

# Count the number of females and males in each sector
plotdata <- group_by(CPS85,sector) %>%
  count(sex)

# Print the data
print(plotdata)

# Construct a ggplot object according requirement above and assign it to 'plt'
plt <- ggplot(plotdata,
              aes(x = sector,
                  y = n))+
  geom_col(aes(fill=sex))+
  geom_text(aes(label=n),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  labs(x = "",
       y = "Number of persons",
       title = "")


# Display the stacked bar chart
plt
```

[image]

[image]

But I want the number in this stacked bar chart be like:
[image]

How could I change my vjust to make the number in the middle of the stacked bar

Comment: Try moving your `fill = sex` from `geom_col()` to `ggplot(aes())`. That is `ggplot(plotdata,aes(x = sector,y = n,fill = sex)) + geom_col() + ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First use `geom_bar` and set `stat = "identity"`. After that use `position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)`. You can use the following code:

```
# Construct a ggplot object according requirement above and assign it to 'plt'
plt <- ggplot(plotdata,aes(x = sector, y = n, fill = sex))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=n), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  labs(x = "",
       y = "Number of persons",
       title = "")


# Display the stacked bar chart
plt
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: In this case it's completely fine to use `geom_col` (like the OP does), the issue here is the position of the `fill` argument.